# How to get different items in a list to interact to get a result?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, for example (the real lists are much longer):

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
list2 = {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
```

I want to create a single list by adding together different elements from different places in each list. For example,

> list3 = (list1<sub>i+1</sub> + list1<sub>i-1</sub>) * (list2<sub>i+1</sub> + list2<sub>i-1</sub>)

where $i$ is the location of the number in the list, e.g. in `list2`, 12 would be $i=4$. I realize the first and last entries in `list3` would either be wrong or non-existent. For example, the 2nd item in `list3` would be $(3+1)(11+9)$ and the 3rd item would be $(4+2)(12+10)$.

I hope that makes sense and I appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you expect for the first element in list3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
(list1[[3 ;;]] + list1[[;; -3]]) (list2[[3 ;;]] + list2[[;; -3]])
```

> `{80, 132, 192, 260, 336}`

The smallest value of i has to be 2, and therefore `list1[3;;]]` represents all values the list of i+1 can assume. Similarly for i-1. The syntax is explained in the documentation for `Part`.

Comment: `list1[[;; Length[list1] - 2]]` can be written as `list1[[;; -3]]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Ty.

Answer (score 3):

Or this:

```
Times @@ (ListCorrelate[{1, 0, 1}, #, {2, -2}, 0] & /@ {list1, list2})

(* {20, 80, 132, 192, 260, 336, 84} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
b = {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

With[{f = (Drop[#, 2] + Drop[#, -2] &)}, f@a f@b]
```

{80, 132, 192, 260, 336}

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it

```
list3 = (RotateLeft[list1]+RotateRight[list1])*(RotateLeft[list2]+RotateRight[list2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `Table` as follows:

```
l = {list1, list2};

Times @@@ Transpose@(Table[#[[i + 1]] + #[[i - 1]], {i, 2, Length@# - 1}] & /@ l)

(*{80, 132, 192, 260, 336}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
list2 = {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
```

---

**Using `ReplaceList`:**

```
a1 = Total /@ ReplaceList[list1, {g___, h_, i_, j_, k___} :> {h, j}];
a2 = Total /@ ReplaceList[list2, {g___, h_, i_, j_, k___} :> {h, j}];
a1 a2
```

---

**Using `Partition`:**

```
a1 = {First@#, Last@#} & /@ Partition[list1, 3, 1] // Map[Total];
a2 = {First@#, Last@#} & /@ Partition[list2, 3, 1] // Map[Total];
a1 a2
```

---

**Using `MovingMap`:**

```
a1 = MovingMap[Total@{First@#, Last@#} &, list1, 2];
a2 = MovingMap[Total@{First@#, Last@#} &, list2, 2];
a1 a2
```

A variation that can allow for more lists:

```
MovingMap[Total@{First@#, Last@#} &, #, 2] & /@ {list1, list2} // 
 Apply[Times]
```

---

*Result:*

> {80, 132, 192, 260, 336}